# Creating URL with headers

Tags: http, url, curl

I can curl a website URL by passing on some header params. I am trying to get the same result on the browser but I cannot build the URL for the browser in the right way.

My curl looks something similar

`curl -X GET -u 'xyz@gmail.com' -H "app-key: some-keys" -H "account-email: procurement@gmail.com" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d 'paused=false' https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.1/checks`

When prompted for the password, i can give the password and Iget the JSON response.

Now I try to build the same URL on my browser. The browser prompts for user name and password which I have already given.

Now my URL looks like this.

`https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.1/users?account-email=procurement@gmail.com&app-key=some-key`

I get a forbidden (as JSON reponse) when I try from the browser and from Curl I get the proper JSON response.
How can I add header params to a URL when pinging from the browser?

Comment: You can't (except when using Javascript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I add header params to a URL when pinging from the browser?

That's not possible. Besides it, from the browser address bar you won't be able to use HTTP methods other than [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1).

So I advise you to you proper tools to target/test your Web API such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Paw](https://paw.cloud/).